# How to put multi array to one csv file with header Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have list like this, I loaded from `xlsx` file

```
import pandas as pd
travel_df = pd.read_excel('./item.xlsx')
data = travel_df.to_dict('records')
```

the `data` like this

```
data = 
[
    {
        'cat': 'A',
        'subCat': 'a1',
    },
    {
        'cat': 'A',
        'subCat': 'a2',
    },
    {
        'cat': 'B',
        'subCat': 'b1',
    },
    {
        'cat': 'B',
        'subCat': 'b2',
    },
    {
        'cat': 'B',
        'subCat': 'b3',
    },
]
```

I want to put this into `CSV` file like this, what is the best and fastest way to do that

```
A     B
--------
a1    b1
a2    b2
      b3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by `DataFrame()` method,`pivot()` method and `apply()` method:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame(data).pivot(columns='cat',values='subCat').apply(lambda x:sorted(x,key=pd.isna))
```

Finally filter out `NaN's`:

```
newdf=newdf[~newdf.isna().all(1)]
```

Output of `newdf`:

```
cat   A     B
0     a1    b1
1     a2    b2
2     NaN   b3
```

Now if you want to save this in csv file then use `to_csv()` method

Comment: how to avoid duplicate records?

Comment: just use `drop_duplicates()` method i.e : `newdf=newdf.drop_duplicates()`